# Как изменить Material на обьекте с двумя Material(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал небольшую модель в Blender 3D и у этой модели есть два материала. Экспортировал ее в .obj файл и импортировал в проект Unity.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить через скрипт один из этих материалов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я помню:

```
renderer.materials[0] = newMaterial; //изменяем материал 1
renderer.materials[1] = newMaterial; //изменяем материал 2
renderer.materials[N] = newMaterial; //изменяем материал N
```